# Swift initializer doesn't return value?

Tags: ios, swift

Swift documentation clearly says.

> Unlike Objective-C initializers, Swift initializers do not return a
>   value.

please explain below syntax.

```
let instanceOfString = String()
```

It does initialize a String object by calling the initializer and return it. Value get assigned to `instanceOfString`. Isn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The swift documentation refers to the syntax of a type's `init` methods.

The syntax omits a return type in the signature and the method usually does not contain a return statement:

```
init() {
}
```

Obviously *the call* of an initializer (`String()`) does return a value. The difference to Objective-C is that the `init` method in pure Swift types is not free to return a different object than the target of the method—it's always the implicitly allocated instance of the target type.

The only exception is that it's possible to return `nil` in failable initializers.

Comment: Objective C introduced a feature to lock the return type to target type by making the return type is of `instancetype`.

Comment: @MadNik You still can return a derived type. That's not possible in Swift—you can't even return a different instance of the exact same type.